# Where is System.out.println() printed in Servlets?

Tags: java, servlets

I have seen in some servlet programs, `System.out.println()` statements. Do they work? If so where are they printed? I have checked the **Web console** in the browser. But I couldn't see it?

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        System.out.println("This is in System.out.println()");
    }
}
```

Because this program is not executed in command prompt, where will the output be printed? Is there any console in the browser that can print this?

Comment: Did you see the server logs?

Comment: This will depend on the server you're running the servlet on. In Websphere, I believe it would wind up in stdout.log.

Comment: @MartinDinov Thank you very much for the replies. I am sleepy and haven't noticed the duplicate.

Comment: @devnull Thanks. I got it, it is in the stdout.txt :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in `tomcat7-stdout-<date>.txt` file. I am using Tomcat.

Comment: Note that it is configurable.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a duplicate question, but, you typically only use System.out.println() in servlets for debugging purposes and what not. Try outputting everything to the logs, by using

log.info("some message")

or

log.error("some error message")

Comment: Thanks. yeah! but System.out is also outputting in the logs only! :)

Comment: Yeah I figured - this is a bit more direct to see if it will work as well. :)

Comment: Sure I'll check it! +Ivan

Answer (score 0):

It is printed on the standard output or wherever it is redirected.

Usually `logs/catalina.out` (if we speak about Tomcat).

Comment: Yes, right. Just thought the same.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't see it there.

Comment: Interesting. How can it be redirected to the text file?

Comment: Type "java MainProgram > out.txt" in a Windows command prompt. It is similar here, I guess.

Comment: Yes, you are right. That redirects to out.txt. But how is it implemented programatically?

Comment: Not that hard, it seems. See here: http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-redirect-standard-output-to-a-file.html

Comment: Simple, `System.setOut(..)`.

Comment: SUPERB @peter.petrov Great catch!!